# Keep original order of requests in JMeter reports

Tags: jmeter, jsr223

I use following code to label requests by response times.

```
if (prev.getTime() > 170 && prev.getTime() < 340) {
    prev.setSampleLabel(prev.getSampleLabel() + " > 170")
} else if (prev.getTime() > 340 && prev.getTime() < 4000) {
    prev.setSampleLabel(prev.getSampleLabel() + " > 340")
} else if (prev.getTime() > 4000 && prev.getTime() < 8000) {
    prev.setSampleLabel(prev.getSampleLabel() + " > 4000")
} else if (prev.getTime() > 8000) {
    prev.setSampleLabel(prev.getSampleLabel() + " > 8000")
}
```

Aggregate report and Summary report contain name of requests in a different order than original one in Thread group. Total number of samples per request is not visible in this way.

Answer (score 1):

JMeter's [Aggregate Report and Summary Report listeners](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-listeners-part-2-listeners-aggregate-data-samples/) always store the Sample Results in **their execution order** and JMeter executes Samplers upside down (or according to the [Logic Controllers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#logic_controllers))

As you can see, **Sampler 4** is the first one because it has been executed first, however it is possible to sort requests by label by clicking the column header since JMeter 3.2):

[image]

Another option to sort requests by label is generating [HTML Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html)

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible also to keep original order of requests? These aren't in alphabetical order, but were ordered on a predefined logical way.